# How to define a new field in a view in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a view based on another table but there are also new fields in the view that are not in the table, The person who did the view did it like this
"Null as Newfield". I want the field to be set to Null but I want the field to be Varchar(1) instead I got a int field. I'm not sure of the exact syntax to make this happen. I cannot find an example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Cast()` ([CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).

```
Cast(NULL AS  Varchar(1)) AS Newfield
```